# Cannot set property 'authToken' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get an access token using MSAL to send to in an azure api request. When I try to set the authToken property to the access token being returned I get the error "Cannot set property of 'authToken' of undefined. Here is the code:

```
export class integrationAccountService
{
  authToken: string;

  constructor( private authService: MsalService, private httpclient: HttpClient, private api: ApiService) {
    this.authToken = "";
  }

  gettoken() {
    this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest).then(function (tokenResponse) {
      console.log(tokenResponse.accessToken);
      this.authToken = tokenResponse.accessToken
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Not sure what I am overlooking here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change .then(function (tokenResponse) { to .then((tokenResponse) => {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `function` for the callback seems to be changing the value of `this`.

Use an arrow function instead:

```
this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest).then(tokenResponse => {
      console.log(tokenResponse.accessToken);
      this.authToken = tokenResponse.accessToken; // "this" was undefined here when using function instead of an arrow function
/* etc. */
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, this has fixed my problem. I will mark as the answer when the time limit is up!